# Handlebars using expression in a expression

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars template that looks like this:

```
<tr>
{{#each columns}}
    <th>
        {{name}}
    </th>
{{/each}}
</tr>

{{#each items}}
    <tr>
        {{each columns}}
            <td>
                {{! I want the items statusString field here for example }}
                {{../dataField}}
            </td>
        {{/each}}
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

and the input to this template looks a bit like this:

```js
columns = [
    {name: 'status', dataField: 'statusString'},
    {name: 'name', dataField: 'name'}
]

items = [
    {status: 1, statusString: 'Active', name: 'item 1'},
    {status: 1, statusString: 'Active', name: 'item 2'},
    {status: 0, statusString: 'Disabled', name: 'item 3'},
    {status: 1, statusString: 'Active', name: 'item 4'}
]
```

in the template i want to iterate each column and display for each item the data that corresponds to each column. But how do I do it in handlebars? I've tried expressions like `{{../{{dataField}}`, `{{{{dataField}}}}` but I can't get anything to work.
I use handlebars in ember.js.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be completed simply by using a helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('helper', function(fieldname, item) {
  return item[fieldname];
});
```

Another way to do it would be using an object iterator, which has been [recently added by handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/pull/272). You can iterate through an object like this

```
var data = {"a": {"test":"test", "test2":"test2"}};
```

with a template

```
{{#each a}}
    {{@key}} - {{this}},
{{/each}}
```

Would print out "test - test, test2 - test2,". If you edited your data you could get the correct output by using this.

Heres a [jsfiddle showing both of these](http://jsfiddle.net/H78Jq/2/).

Comment: I make a little correction to you fiddle to make this sample workable again, here you are: http://jsfiddle.net/XVCrC/1/